# Is there any difference between different quotes in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, quotes

What is the difference between following assignments:

```
>>> a = 'h'  
>>> a
'h'  
>>> b = "h"
>>> b  
'h'
>>> c = '''h'''
>>> c  
'h'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference.

The only difference between `'` and `"` is that you can use one inside the other. E.g.

```
x = "Hey that's my bike!"
y = 'I responded, "Yes, it is."'
```

Strings enclosed in `'''` and `"""` can contain both `'` or `"` and can span multiple lines.